# Is there a way to selectively highlight lines of code in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

One of my team members recently added some wonderful instrumentation to some complex (but elegant code) in one of our products (so we could understand what it does!) by adding a lot of logger.DebugFormat statements. Despite the huge perceived value in doing this, one of the Developers in my team has started moaning that it makes it difficult to pick out the real code that does stuff. I think this could be easily resolved if there was some way of getting Visual Studio to change the colour of a specific string such as logger.DebugFormat.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free VS plug-in for this purpose;

[Download here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb/file/15305/0/SelectionHighlight.vsix)

This extension will highlight all occurrences of a selected word in the current document and display a glyph on the left margin.
This allows for fast visualization of a specific word used throughout the document, including ones in comments.

Steps:

1) Install the extension and verified that it is enabled in the Tools->Extension Manager.

2) In the editor window, select a word with a mouse or keyboard.

All occurrences of the word selected should be highlighted in the current document.

Comment: we are looking for permanent highlighting so we can differentiate the logging lines from the main code lines, much like the comments which standout as green compared to the rest of the code. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[KeywordClassifier](https://github.com/tomasr/KeywordClassifier) Visual Studio extension shows how to customize the syntax highlighting. It also allows you to customize which keywords get highlighted.